# Showing continuity for complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Is the function
$$
f(z)
=
\begin{cases}\frac{z^2+2iz-1}{2z^2-iz+1}, & x\neq-i\\\\
0, & \text{Otherwise}\end{cases}
$$ continuous at -i? Explain your answer.

I am kinda unsure on how to do this. Do I use some eposon delta definition? If so, can someone tell me the definition please because we weren't given it explicitly. If this was real analysis, I would just consider the two sided limit at the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that 
$$z^2+2iz-1=(z+i)^2, \quad 2z^2-iz+1=(z-i)(2z+i)$$

We see that $-i$ is not a root of $2z^2-iz+1$, thus we can find $d>0$ and $r_1>0$ such that

$$|2z^2-iz+1|\geq d,\quad\forall |z+i|<r_1$$

Also, $-i$ is a root of $z^2+2iz-1$, so for any $\varepsilon>0$, we can find $r_2>0$ s.t.

$$|z^2+2iz-1|^2<\varepsilon d,\quad\forall |z+i|<r_2$$

hence

$$\left|\frac{z^2+2iz-1}{2z^2-iz+1}\right|\leq \frac{\varepsilon d}{d}=\varepsilon,\quad\forall |z+i|<\min\{r_1,r_2\}$$

which means

$$\lim_{z\to-i}|f(z)|=\lim_{z\to-i}\left|\frac{z^2+2iz-1}{2z^2-iz+1}\right|=0$$

thus

$$\lim_{z\to-i}f(z)=0$$

Comment: I really dont understand what you did here. Would you be able to expand on your answer if possible please.

Comment: I've included more details.